# Java JPA entity OneToMany of same entity cause stack overflow in assembler ricorsion

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, jpa

I try to develop a hierarchical model for users in Java Web project.
I implemented database data objects with Java Spring, JPA and Hibernate.
Any "User" has a list of children of same type "User" with a OneToMany relationship.

**Class User**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "emsusers")
public class User extends DomainEntity implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "username", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @JoinColumn(name = "role", nullable = false)
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Role role;

    @JoinColumn(name = "parent")
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private User parent;

    @JoinColumn(name = "children")
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private final Set<User> children;

    @JoinColumn(name = "servers")
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Server> servers;

    private User(String username, String password, Role role, User parent, Set<Server> servers) {

        super(UUID.randomUUID().toString());        

        if (username == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("username == null");
        }
        this.username = username;

        if (password == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("password == null");
        }
        this.password = password;

        if (role == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("role == null");
        }
        this.role = role;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.children = Sets.newHashSet();

        if (servers == null) {
            this.servers = Sets.newHashSet();
        } 
        else {
            this.servers = Sets.newHashSet(servers);
        }
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public User getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public ImmutableSet<User> getChildren() {
        return ImmutableSet.copyOf(children);
    }

    public ImmutableSet<Server> getServers() {
        return ImmutableSet.copyOf(servers);
    }

    public void updatePassword(String oldPassword, String newPassword) {

        if (!this.password.equals(oldPassword)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Wrong old password.");
        }

        if (oldPassword.equals(newPassword)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("New password is equal to old password.");
        }

        this.password = newPassword;
    }

    public void update(Role role, Set<Server> servers) {
        this.role = role;
        this.servers = Sets.newHashSet(servers);
    }

    public void addChild(User child) {
        this.children.add(child);
    }

    public void delChild(User child) {
        this.children.remove(child);
    }

    public static User of(String username, String password, Role role, User parent, Set<Server> servers) {
        return new User(username, password, role, parent, servers);
    }

    // Solo per JPA
    protected User() {
        this.children = Sets.newHashSet();
    }
}
```

Now I defined some services, for example this service return pageable list of all users created from a parent user :

**Service**

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    @Override
    public PageDTO<UserDTO> getListByParent(String id, Pageable page) {
        final User parent = userRepository.findOne(id);
        if (parent == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("User parent not exist.");
        }

        final Page<User> usersPage = userRepository.findAll(UserSpecifications.withParent(parent), page);
        return UserAssembler.toDTOPage(usersPage);
    }
```

Then class UserAssembler implements some methods, in this case the service use two critical methods :

**Convert User to UserDTO**

```
public static UserDTO toDTO(User input) {
        final UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
        dto.setId(input.getIdentity());
        dto.setUsername(input.getUsername());
        dto.setPassword(input.getPassword());
        dto.setRole(RoleAssembler.toDTO(input.getRole()));

        if (input.getParent() != null) {
            dto.setParent(UserAssembler.toDTO(input.getParent()));
        }

        if (input.getChildren().isEmpty() == false) {
            dto.getChildren().addAll(toListDTO(input.getChildren()));
        }

        if (input.getServers() != null) {
            dto.getServers().addAll(ServerAssembler.toListString(input.getServers()));
        }

        return dto;
    }
```

**Convert Set to List**

```
public static List<UserDTO> toListDTO(Set<User> input) {
        final List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>();
        for (User usr : input) {
            users.add(toDTO(usr));
        }        
        return users;
    }
```

As you can see the method "toDTO" call the method "toListDTO", that called method "toDTO", this recursion cause a java stack overflow error when service called by a controller to produce json rest api.

I try to limit OneToMany children using @BatchSize annotation but not solve error.

Can you help me or suggest solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, a UserDTO has a parent UserDTO, which has child UserDTOs, which have a parent UserDTO, which have child UserDTOs, etc. etc. So yes, that's an infinite recursion loop. Hibernate can't do anything about it. The design of your DTOs is the problem. Choose to have a parent in your DTOs, or children, but not both.

Answer (score 0):

These calls within the toDTO method will cycle infinitely,

```
dto.setParent(UserAssembler.toDTO(input.getParent()));
```

and

```
toListDTO(Set<User> input)
```

The first code calls toDTO method on the parent which in turn calls the toListDTO, this goes back to child that originally calls the toDTO on the parent. So the infinite cycle goes on...

My suggestion, don't use the same toDTO method on the parent, create another method (toUserDTO )that converts a User to its DTO excluding both getParent and getChildren method.

```
public static UserDTO toUserDTO(User input) {
    final UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
    dto.setId(input.getIdentity());
    dto.setUsername(input.getUsername());
    dto.setPassword(input.getPassword());
    dto.setRole(RoleAssembler.toDTO(input.getRole()));

    if (input.getServers() != null) {
        dto.getServers().addAll(ServerAssembler.toListString(input.getServers()));
    }

    return dto;
}
```

Then on toListDTO, modify the loop such as

```
public static List<UserDTO> toListDTO(Set<User> input) {
    final List<UserDTO> users = new ArrayList<>();
    for (User usr : input) {
        users.add(toUserDTO(usr));
    }        
    return users;
}
```

This way, it won't recurse back to toDTO method infinitely.